# Como colocar projeto no Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

Estou tentando colocar o meu projeto no repositório do professor e terminarei ficando sem nota por não conseguir, e fiz os seguintes procedimentos;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele estáva indo bem, porém quando chegou no ultimo comando deu erro como vocês podem ver;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o repositório já havia sido criado previamente? ele está vazio ou já tem conteúdo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos supor que você esteja trabalhando com um repositório GIT criado previamente e que já contém alguns arquivos.

## Passo 1 - Sincronizando o repositório

Escolha uma pasta qualquer do seu sistema e digite:

```
git clone ENDERECO_DO_REPOSITORIO
```

Esse endereço pode ser obtido no canto superior direito do bitbucket, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Passo 2 - Verificando as diferenças

Com o repositório sincronizado, você pode editar/criar os arquivos necessários para a execução da sua demanda. Quando quiser verificar o estado do seu repositório local em relação ao repositório remoto, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
git status
```

## Passo 3 - Adicionando novos arquivos

Caso você tenha adicionado algum novo arquivo ao repositório, você precisa adicionar na lista de arquivos gerenciados pelo GIT. Isso pode ser feito utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
git add .
```

## Passo 4 - Realizando o commit

Após adicionar todos os arquivos, é hora de realizar o [`commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). Para isso, utilize o comando:

```
git commit -am "mensagem explicando o que foi feito"
```

## Passo 5 - Executando alterações adicionais

Existem novas demandas a serem realizadas? Basta continuar trabalhando normalmente. Quando finalizar basta executar os passos 2 a 4 novamente. Após a finalização de todas as demandas, é hora de enviar as alterações realizadas para o repositório remoto. Para isso, continue no passo 6.

## Passo 6 - Enviando as alterações para o repositório remoto

Caso você tenha finalizado o trabalho, é hora de realizar o [`push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push). Para isso basta utilizar o comando:

```
git push
```

Comment: No último comando, só faltou configurar o `master` remoto como upstream. Basta rodar `git push -u origin master` na primeira vez e `git push` nas vezes seguintes.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti se você clonar um repositório já existente, não é necessário executar o `git push -u origin master` na primeira vez. Ele já vai ser o seu upstream padrão.

Comment: fiz uma atualização na postagem, em resumo quando fui colocar o ultimo comando para efetivar o commit deu erro, eu digitei isso git push -u origin master, me ajuda ai por favor

Comment: ele pedi uma senha, quando eu coloco que ele falha, estou colocando a senha certa do meu repositório, mas o que quero fazer e colocar o meu projeto no repositório do professor.

Comment: @wladyband se você seguir o passo a passo (e tiver acesso ao repositório do professor), vai funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: desculpe Romulo, mas você viu a atualização da minha postagem? baseado na ultima figura que coloquei o que deve está acontecendo? eu preciso da sua compreensão, por favor.

Comment: eu não tenho acesso ao repositório do professor, eu quero é colocar o meu projeto no repositório dele sem eu precisa da senha dele, me entende?

Comment: @wladyband você não precisa da senha dele para ter acesso ao repositório. Basta ele adicionar o seu usuário ao repositório dele com permissão de escrita. A senha que você vai utilizar é a sua mesmo.