# Guardar projeto do android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-drive-api, dropbox

Estou fazendo um app e meu maior medo é perder o projeto(se meu pc quebrar por exemplo) quero saber se dá para guardar o projeto no Dropbox ou Google Drive sem danificar o app, ou se tem outra forma de eu guardar com segurança o projeto

Comment: Recomendo você utilizar o [GitHub](https://github.com/) ou se for privado podes usar o [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). Pois o **GitHub** nessa parte tem que para um **X** por mês.

Comment: poderia especificar melhor, eu poderia guardar meu projeto lá? eu teria segurança?

Comment: Se é projeto privado coloca no [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), mas tenha certeza que você vai especificar no site que é um repositório **privado**.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! vou verificar! nesses casos eu poderia ir usando e atualizando automaticamente?(como acontece no Dropbox)

Comment: Você nunca usou o [Git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) / [Bitbucket](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/bitbucket/info) / [GitHub](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/github/info) antes? Leia essa pergunta [Como colocar projeto no Bitbucket?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91857) e a resposta, pesquise mais sobre ele, tem varios tutoriais no **Youtube** em *Português*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas para guardar o app é fazendo um backup da pasta "src" do projeto, ali estará todo seu código classes, activity's, strings, manifest, etc, para restaurar o projeto crie um projeto em branco e substitua a pasta "src". Eu costumo criar um .zip e guardar no Google Drive ou Dropbox, outra forma é criar um repositório no [github](https://github.com/) ou [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) geralmente é mais utilizado, eu também utilizo, tendo as possibilidades de repositórios públicos ou privados(este é pago no github) e versionamento dos seus arquivos.